# Dax function Date is giving error : "Wrong Data type"

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to create a measure that subtracts 2 months from the date column "Sale_Date". However, when I use the below measure I get error  "Wrong Data type". Something is wrong in day argument of date function. Because when I hardcode the day value , I start getting results

```
Min_Date = 
var val = SELECTEDVALUE(EX4[Sale_Date])
var month = month(SELECTEDVALUE(EX4[Sale_Date]))-2
var Year = Year(SELECTEDVALUE(EX4[Sale_Date]))
var Day = day(SELECTEDVALUE(EX4[Sale_Date]))
return
DATE(Year,month,Day)
```

You can replicate this scenario using the below calculated table :

```
EX4 = DATATABLE("Sale_Date",datetime,{{"2022-10-01"},{"2022-10-09"},{"2022-11-12"},{"2022-11-23"}})
```

Below is the image of visual which is giving error because of this measure:

[image: Below is the image of visual which is giving error because of this measure]

Now when I hardcode the day value, I start getting output:

[image]

I do not want to solve using calculated column. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this measure instead:

```
Min_Date = 
VAR thisdate = MAX(EX4[Sale_Date])
RETURN
    DATE(YEAR(thisdate), MONTH(thisdate) - 2, DAY(thisdate))
```

Works for Jan and Feb too.

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem?

Comment: Thankyou Peter. Your solution worked like a charm. Apologies for replying late. Got busy with family this weekend. However, I am still wondering what was wrong with selectedvalue function. selectedvalue when replaced with MAX started working

Answer (score 0):

the error is caused by this line:

var month = month(SELECTEDVALUE(EX4[Sale_Date]))-2

for January and February this value will be -1 and 0. So it can't be passed to the date function
[image]

Comment: Thanks Bartek for your reply. However my sample data does not have Jan or Feb month. The date column is in (dd-mm-yyyy) format. My sample data has only 2 months October and November.